# Angularjs call function when the controller is load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I have a little problem with controllers in AngularJs.

I have one controllers and some other controllers into the first controller. Basically i have this :

```
<body ng-app="scopeInheritance">
    <div class="spicy">
        <div ng-controller="MainController">
            <p>Good {{timeOfDay}}, {{name}}!</p>

            <div ng-controller="ChildController">
                <p>Good {{timeOfDay}}, {{name}}!</p>
                <p ng-if="valide()">Heelo i'm the if</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And my .js

```
var myApp = angular.module('scopeInheritance', []);

myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.timeOfDay = 'morning';
  $scope.name = 'Nikki';
  $scope.testCtrl1 = true;
}]);

myApp.controller('ChildController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Mattie';
  $scope.timeOfDay = 'aternoon';
  $scope.test = true;   

  $scope.valide = function () {
    alert("i'm the function validate");
    if($scope.testCtrl1 && $scope.test)
      return true;
  };
}]);
```

I want to call the function valide() to show some text. The function can return true or false depending of the value one the controller `ChildController`

The problem is : the function valide() is calling at every controllers.
This is normal, but how can i limite that ? The function valide() need to be call when the controller `ChildController` is load.

Maybe it was unclear, i made a live exemple : http://plnkr.co/edit/AM9loq4VRkL16mX8LR1v?p=preview

You can see two alert.

**EDIT = valide() return true or false, depending on the value of the controllers ChildController and MainController**

Comment: why are you concerned about it being called twice? does it matter?

Comment: Yes ^^ i'm not sure it was the best things to do, so i'm asking if their is better solutions.

Comment: Could you just call the `valide()` immediately in the controller constructor and store the result into `$scope` as some variable e.g. `$scope.isValid`. Then use that in the `ng-if` instead of a function expression?

Comment: @runTarm nop because valid() also depends of values of the second constructor

Comment: @Droïdeka What would prevent you from accessing the values of the second constructor if the `valide()` is called right away? I think it should works.